# add subscript to TikZ figure of neural networks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I have the following TikZ code...

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for aligned
%\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifthen
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for arrow size
\usepackage[outline]{contour} % glow around text
\contourlength{1.4pt}

\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!70!red!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{red!30!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{green!30!black}
\tikzstyle{node}=[thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{node in}=[node,green!20!black,draw=mygreen!30!black,fill=mygreen!25]
\tikzstyle{node hidden}=[node,blue!20!black,draw=myblue!30!black,fill=myblue!20]
\tikzstyle{node convol}=[node,orange!20!black,draw=myorange!30!black,fill=myorange!20]
\tikzstyle{node out}=[node,red!20!black,draw=myred!30!black,fill=myred!20]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[thick,mydarkblue] %,line cap=round
\tikzstyle{connect arrow}=[-{Latex[length=4,width=3.5]},thick,mydarkblue,shorten <=0.5,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
  node 1/.style={node in},
  node 2/.style={node hidden},
  node 3/.style={node out},
}
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}


% NEURAL NETWORK with coefficients, shifted
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.2cm,y=1.4cm]
  \message{^^JNeural network, shifted}
  \readlist\Nnod{4,5,3} % array of number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Nstr{q,m,K} % array of string number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Cstr{\strut Z,w^{(\prev)},\beta^{TN}} %array of coefficient symbol per layer: <<<- I think HERE I HAVE TO CHANGE SOMETHING!!! 
  \def\yshift{0.5} % shift last node for dots
  
  \message{^^J  Layer}
  \foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \message{\lay,}
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
                 \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\lay]");
                 \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
      % NODES
      \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\Cstr[\lay]_{\index}$};
      
      % CONNECTIONS
      \ifnum\lay>1 % connect to previous layer
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
          \draw[connect,white,line width=1.2] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          %\draw[connect] (N\prev-\j.0) -- (N\lay-\i.180); % connect to left
        }
      \fi % else: nothing to connect first layer
      
    }
    \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\vdots$};
  }
  % LABELS
  \node[above=5,align=center,mygreen!60!black] at (N1-1.90) {input\\[-0.2em]layer};
  \node[above=1,align=center,myblue!60!black] at (N2-1.90) {hidden layer};
  \node[above=10,align=center,myred!60!black] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {output\\[-0.2em]layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... which produces the following figure:

[image]

---

However, I would like to have something like the image below where I have $_n$ before the index of each $\beta$. Could someone help me with that? I am getting

[image]

Comment: On a side note, please consider to use only `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` which is deprecated nowadays.

Comment: I am sorry @SebGlav but could you indicate where should I change what you mention?

Comment: Wherever you used `tikzstyle`, you should use `tikzset` instead. You mixed both commands and the former is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made 2 changes :

```
\readlist\Cstr{\strut Z_{\index},w_{\index}^{(\prev)},\beta_{n\index}^{TN}} 
%array of coefficient symbol per layer.
```

and

```
%NODES
\node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\Cstr[\lay]$};
```

My reasoning was to try to put a subscript on `beta`. But, that leads to a double script error. I checked where  the other subscript was. I found `_\index`. Thus I moved `_index` to the definition of `\Cstr`.
Looks like it works
[image]